# Concerns about scheduled tasks

Tags: parallelization

I'd like to know how `CreateScheduledTask` and `StartScheduledTask` work internally.

When I run the following code:

```
Dynamic[x]
task = CreateScheduledTask[x = RandomReal[]];
StartScheduledTask[task];
```

I see (using ProcessThreadsView) that the internal thread UserRequest-3532 of WolframKernel.exe is resumed and starts to do the job, when I stop the task using:

```
StopScheduledTask[task];
```

the thread UserRequest-3532 suspend.

But if I run two scheduled tasks using the following code:

```
(*first task*)
Dynamic[x]
task = CreateScheduledTask[x = RandomReal[]];
StartScheduledTask[task];

(*second task*)
Dynamic[y]
task2 = CreateScheduledTask[y = RandomReal[]];
StartScheduledTask[task2];
```

I see always the same thread (UserRequest-3532) that resume and do both jobs.

I expected that for every `CreateScheduledTask` call, MathKernel.exe would start a new thread, and when I call `StartScheduledTask`, the new thread should resume and do the job. In this way I expected to have one-thread for every scheduled task, but clearly I missed something.

So I'm starting to think that using the scheduled task group of functions is not the way get multithreading with *Mathematica*.

Comment: Isn't it [Parallel Computing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ParallelComputing.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: You mean that if I wrap two tasks in Parallelize[] the MathKernel create two different threads and assign each one to a single math task ?

Comment: I meant that the link provided has documentation that would not fit in this margin.